# Smoothing a 3d surface

Tags: geometry

I have a 3d surface defined by a set of 10 $x$, $y$ and $z$ coordinates, $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$, $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$, $(x_3,y_3,z_3)$.... $(x_{10},y_{10},z_{10})$. This surface is not flat, I would like a general way to find an equivalent flat surface by "averaging" the $x$, $y$ and $z$ coordinates somehow. Does a simple operation exist for this kind of application?

EDIT: This is for finding the average roof height for a building, I also know the boundary of the roof

Comment: No it is a set of several x y z points... Like 10 of them (x1,y1,z1), (x2,y2,z2), (x3,y3,z3).... (x10,y10,z10)

Comment: Why don't you just fit a plane, and then for each point make some average between itself and its projection onto the fitted plane?

Comment: Perhaps you want linear regression? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression

Comment: Do you want a smooth "flat" surface or a plane ? Can you display your point cloud ?

Comment: Yves, if I am understanding you correctly, a smooth "flat" surface could be inclined whereas a plane can not? If so, then I am looking for a plane.

Comment: @user32882 There are tons of ways the to fit a plane. Without any context except for the wish for simplicity, my suggestion would be just randomly choose 3 of your points and then find the plane that intersect these.

Comment: The context is I am trying to find the "average roof height" for a complicated roofline for a building. I also woould like to take all 10 points into consideration

Comment: Do you know the boundary of the roof? (I mean where it intersects the wall)

Comment: Yes of course, I know the boundary of the roof

Comment: Map the x,y coordinates to a set of triangles on the x,y plane.  For each triangle find the area.  And for each, find the average z coordinate of the vertexes.  Multiply the average z by the area.  Sum them, divide by the total area of the triangles.

Comment: If you like the approach, you could partition the interior of the boundary with respect to the equivalence relation defined by which point is nearest, and use the area for each class in a weighed average of the z values. The regions could look like this http://i.imgur.com/vtzaDQG.png

Comment: Is there a systematic/rational way to partition the points?